# not working in my Fragment: getContext(), getActivity() or getSherlockActivity()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to start a MediaPlayer instance in my sherlock-fragment but the context isn't working.

I've tried  getContext(), getActivity() and getSherlockActivity()

Trying to surround it with isAttached() wasn't successful either.

Error
"The method isAttached() is undefined for the type Fragment_1"

Is my mistake somewhere else? Thank you.

```
public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment{

public Button b1;
public Button b2;
public Button b3;

public Button r1;
public Button r2;

public Button s1;
public Button s3;

private static String mFileName = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    if( isAttached() ) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sechs);
        }

    View vb1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    b1 = (Button)vb1.findViewById(R.id.play);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View vb1) {
            mp.start();       
        }
    });


    View vb2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    b2 = (Button)vb2.findViewById(R.id.pause);

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

        public void onClick(View vb2) {                  
            mp.pause();              
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: What does "the context isn't working" mean? `getActivity()` is how you get your `SherlockActivity` instance from your `SherlockFragment`. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Fragments/ActionBar

Comment: Well, before using fragments my code was working fine in an Activity with the line "final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sechs);" I just need an alternative for MainActivity.this now, as I changed to fragments.

Comment: error: 'unreachable code' when I use just "MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getSherlockActivity(), R.raw.sechs);"

Comment: Well, that's because of your `isAttached()` block. `mp` is not visible outside of that `if` statement. Your code won't even compile, as `mp` is not defined for your `onClick()` listener.

Comment: I tried to say: I receive 'unreachable code' without the is Attached() if-block

Comment: I have to put all my methods and variables inside OnCreateView, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment{

public Button b1;

public View view;

public MediaPlayer mp = null;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sechs);

    Button b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.play);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          mp.start(); 
      }

    });

  return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using getActivity() check isAdded() fragment method

Answer (score -1):

At "onCreateView" life cycle, fragment is not attached to activity.
You need to access to activity in "onActivityCreated".

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /** You can try getActivity() here. it should not be null. **/
}
```

Comment: No, by the time `onCreateView()` is called, the fragment should have access to `getActivity()`.

Comment: It has access but getActivity() returns null in onCreatedView() which I am guessing `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(null, R.raw.sechs);` is not what questioner wanted.

Comment: "It has access but getActivity() returns null in onCreatedView()" -- no, `getActivity()` in `onCreateView()` will return the `Activity` that hosts the fragment. Otherwise, you could not have the `ViewGroup` or the `LayoutInflater` parameters to `onCreateView()`, because those are created using the activity.